# error with font awesome on webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

When I run my webpack build command

`webpack --config .\webpack.config.vendor.js`

I am receiving the following errors;

> Webpack : TypeError: dep.getResourceIdentifier is not a function At
>   line:1 char:1
>   + webpack --config .\webpack.config.vendor.js
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (TypeError: dep.... not a function:String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
>
> ```
> at addDependency (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:387:30)
> at iterationOfArrayCallback (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:78:3)
> at addDependenciesBlock (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:407:5)
> at Compilation.processModuleDependencies (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:418:4)
> at afterBuild (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:686:13)
> at buildModule.err (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:714:8)
> at callback (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:342:35)
> at module.build.error (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:378:12)
> at DllModule.build (C:\Users\matt\Source\Repos\bemfeito\Bemfeito\Bemfeito.Services.Public\node_modules\webpack\lib\DllModule.js:36:10)
> at Compilation.buildModule (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:346:10)
> at moduleFactory.create (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:702:12)
> at DllModuleFactory.create (C:\Users\matt\Source\Repos\bemfeito\Bemfeito\Bemfeito.Services.Public\node_modules\webpack\lib\DllModuleFactory.js:16:3)
> at semaphore.acquire (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:649:18)
> at Semaphore.acquire (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\Semaphore.js:16:4)
> at Compilation._addModuleChain (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:648:18)
> at Compilation.addEntry (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:732:8)
> at compiler.plugin (C:\Users\matt\Source\Repos\bemfeito\Bemfeito\Bemfeito.Services.Public\node_modules\webpack\lib\DllEntryPlugin.js:28:16)
> at AsyncParallelHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:24:12),
> ```
>
> :7:1)
>       at AsyncParallelHook.lazyCompileHook [as _callAsync] (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:35:21)
>       at hooks.beforeCompile.callAsync.err (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:475:20)
>       at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:24:12),
>   :6:1)
>       at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook [as _callAsync] (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:35:21)
>       at Compiler.compile (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:468:28)
>       at readRecords.err (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:216:11)
>       at Compiler.readRecords (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:338:11)
>       at hooks.run.callAsync.err (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:213:10)
>       at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:24:12),
>   :6:1)
>       at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook [as _callAsync] (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:35:21)
>       at hooks.beforeRun.callAsync.err (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:210:19)
>       at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:24:12),
>   :15:1)
>       at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook [as _callAsync] (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:35:21)
>       at Compiler.run (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:207:24)
>       at runWit hDependencies (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\MultiCompiler.js:253:15)
>       at asyncLib.map (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\MultiCompiler.js:177:6)
>       at arrayEachIndex (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2494:9)
>       at Object.map (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2845:9)

My webpack.config.vendor.js is as follows;

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const treeShakableModules = [
    '@angular/animations',
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/forms',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    'zone.js',
];
const nonTreeShakableModules = [
    'bootstrap',
    'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
    'es6-promise',
    'es6-shim',
    'event-source-polyfill',
    'jquery',
    'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
    'node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css'
];
const allModules = treeShakableModules.concat(nonTreeShakableModules);

module.exports = (env) => {
    const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('vendor.css');
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        resolve: { extensions: [ '.js' ] },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?|$)/, use: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }
            ]
        },
        output: {
            publicPath: 'dist/',
            filename: '[name].js',
            library: '[name]_[hash]'
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }), // Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\@angular\b.*\b(bundles|linker)/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14898
            new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^vertx$/) // Workaround for https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise/issues/100
        ]
    };

    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        entry: {
            // To keep development builds fast, include all vendor dependencies in the vendor bundle.
            // But for production builds, leave the tree-shakable ones out so the AOT compiler can produce a smaller bundle.
            vendor: isDevBuild ? allModules : nonTreeShakableModules
        },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist') },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, use: extractCSS.extract({ use: isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' }) }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            extractCSS,
            new webpack.DllPlugin({
                path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
                name: '[name]_[hash]'
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
        ])
    });

    const serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        target: 'node',
        resolve: { mainFields: ['main'] },
        entry: { vendor: allModules.concat(['aspnet-prerendering']) },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp', 'dist'),
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
        },
        module: {
            rules: [ { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, use: ['to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' ] } ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllPlugin({
                path: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
                name: '[name]_[hash]'
            })
        ]
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
}
```

My package.json is as follows;

```
{
  "name": "Bemfeito.Services.Public",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.10.0-beta.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "9.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "2.0.1",
    "@types/chai": "4.1.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.6",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.5",
    "angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "angular2-useful-swiper": "5.0.1",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.9",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.12",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-beta.0",
    "file-loader": "1.1.11",
    "flag-icon-css": "3.0.0",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "html-loader": "0.5.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.9.1",
    "jquery": "3.3.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.7",
    "karma": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.1",
    "karma-webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "2.0.2",
    "ngx-rating": "0.0.9",
    "popper.js": "1.12.9",
    "preboot": "6.0.0-beta.1",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "5.5.6",
    "style-loader": "0.20.3",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "typescript": "2.7.1",
    "url-loader": "0.6.2",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.21.0",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.14"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here please? I cannot find anything else regarding this issue so assume it is something I am doing locally.

I am running Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Community, inside the .net core 2 angular SPA template.

Comment: You are using an old version of `file-loader`. Can you try updating

Comment: @lukas-reineke thanks for the reply. I have tried updating the above to `"file-loader": "1.1.11"` (and I have downgraded webpack to be `"webpack": "^3.11.0"`) I get the error `+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (TypeError: dep.... not a function:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
    at addDependency (C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:387:30)` any ideas with this?

Comment: can you update the question with the full error message and the versions of all dependencies please

Comment: @lukas-reineke sorry for the delay I have updated witht he output and the `packages.json`, `webpack.vendor.config.js` and output.

Comment: Its weird, the error looks like a webpack 4 bug. https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6675 can you delete your `node_modules` folder and install again to make sure everything has the version it should have?

Comment: @lukas-reineke ok I did the following, 1- deleted the `node_modules` folder and ran `npm install` this installed all the packages. I then ran `npm install webpack@^3.11.0 -g --save-dev` to install webpack globally. (I did this for the `webpack-hot-middleware` and `webpack-merge` as well). Then when I run webpack --config again I get the same error?

Comment: Also just to clarify if I look at the dependencies in my solution explorer, it is showing webpack @ 3.11.0 and not 4 (I did see that Git issue).

Comment: As a rule of thumb, always avoid installing dependencies globally. You might want to use a different version somewhere else. Webpack 4 introduced `webpack-cli` which splits the cli tool from webpack out in a different package. Can you check if you still have that installed? And if you do remove it.

Comment: @lukas-reineke thanks for your help. As you said the fact Webpack 4 had beeninstallled globally seemed to overrule to local installation. So by deleting the global packages and then installing v3 globally fixed the issue.

Comment: If you want to post the answer I'll accept it :) Also by the way webpack did have to be installed globally as it threw a load of errors (i didnt log these though) when just running it locally for some reason??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Awesome we figured this out.
So the answer was just version problems. The recent change to webpack 4 makes this quite cumbersome. 4 is not quite stable but if you use 3 you have to check every package, because most of the ones who support 4 are not backward compatible.

As for why you are having issues running webpack locally, I don't know. But I also don't use Windows.
You should try to find a solution for this though, versioning gets way harder if you have to do it globally once you start having more than one project.

Comment: Just to add the way we worked this around was to delete all global folders for `webpack`, `webpack-hot-middleware` and `webpack-merge` and local node_modules folder. Then reinstall each globally using -g